# Instantiating QML object in existing C++ QT Project

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qqmlcomponent, qquickwidget

We have an existing QT project written in C++, and we want to add something like the mapViewer example project to our existing UI. We can't figure out how to instantiate the mapViewer, and invoke the method that initializes/displays it. Following online help, we came up with the function below, that returns a QQuickWidget which we can add to a UI element. We keep getting an error that the created component never gets to be ready, so the function does not work.

```
QQuickWidget *buildMap(QWidget *parent)
{
    QQmlEngine *engine = new QQmlEngine;
    QQmlComponent component(engine, "qrc://mapviewer.qml");

    QObject *object = component.create();
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(object, "initializeMap");

    QQuickWidget *map = new QQuickWidget(engine, parent);
    return map;
}
```

It does not make a ton of sense to us that we are creating an object using the mapViewer component, and then just forgetting about it, but the examples we found online have a flow similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this instead:

```
QQuickWidget *buildMap(QWidget *parent) {
    QQuickWidget *map = new QQuickWidget(parent);
    map->setSource(QUrl("qrc://mapviewer.qml"));
    map->show();
    return map;
}
```

As for the `initializeMap` method, maybe call it in `mapviewer.qml`'s `onCompleted`? If you insist on calling it from C++, you can still get to the object thorugh `map->rootObject()`

Also, when creating components and objects, be that from C++ or QML, it is always a nice idea to check the status and output error strings if any, you don't just assume it will all work and then wonder why it doesn't.